# PyCharm raw_input and command line

Tags: python, command-line, pycharm

I'm a starter with PyCharm.
I try to run some code like this:

```
name = raw_input()
print name
```

I checked the option **Show Command Line afterwards**, but I can't enter anything because the command line directly showed up after I run the code.

Can anyone tell me how I can get command line after I input something and get results?

Comment: You don't need to check that option.

Comment: Why do you need the command line after your program has finished?

Answer (score 0):

you need to run your .py  file from command
for example your code is written in `test.py` file

1. open your command
2. with using `cd` command go to directory where is your `test.py` file has been save
3. `python test.py` <-- type that command.